# Ajuda para entender localStorage.js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Gostaria de uma ajuda para enter o [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage) em *javascript*.
Objetivo: Fazer uma função de salvar informação no input idêntico ao wordpress, exemplo:

[image: - Visit http://prntscr.com/hkec1z]
 [image: ![- Visit http://prntscr.com/hkec5w]
 [image: - Visit http://prntscr.com/hkecap]

No terceiro *print* é o que eu quero, se ele não digitar nada no campo de senha, mas já digitou no de login, fica salvo, sem precisa redigitar.

código que estou usando:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function digGet(){
    // Cria um item "usuario" com valor "Thiago Belem"
    var login = document.getElementById("user_login");
    window.localStorage.setItem('usuario', login);
    saveGet();
}

function saveGet(){
    // Depois, em outra página ou aba, recupera esse item
    var usuario = window.localStorage.getItem('usuario');
    document.getElementById('user_login').value = usuario;
}

function delGet(){

    // Remove o item
    window.localStorage.removeItem('usuario');
}
</script>
```

quero transformar em php isso, para que o getItem('usuario'); seja o usuário digitado no *input* pelo usuário.

Se alguém souber me ajudar, ficarei muito grato.

Comment: você quer salvar um usuário sem senha? e no caso de diversas pessoas com o mesmo nome se cadastrarem ?

Comment: não, quero que o cara apos digitar um usuário, fique salvo no campo mesmo ele dando F5

Comment: Geralmente os navegadores fazem isso sem precisar usar cookies ou localStorage. Realmente você acha que isto é uma funcionalidade relevante?

Comment: Sim, acho, pois assim meu sistema de login ficará perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Não é recomendado autocompletar senha de usuários a partir do sistema, esta deve ser sempre uma escolha do usuário.

Os Browsers inclusive alertam sobre essa pŕatica como uma falha grave na segurança.

Caso deseje manter a seção do usuário para que ele não necessite sempre efetuar o login, é uma boa escolha usar [cookies](/questions/tagged/cookies)

- [Usando Cookeis com PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.cookies.php)
- [Usando Cookeis com Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: Olha, pelos cookies agradeço, mas não é essa a minha necessidade, pois meu sistema login o usuário que escolhe se fica ou sai, minha necessidade mesmo é fazer só salvar o login no input.

Answer (score 0):

Independente da relevância de utilizar isso, que acho que já foi bem explicada, o que faltou no seu código é rodar a sua funçar saveGet() quando a página é carregada.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function digGet(){
    // Cria um item "usuario" com valor "Thiago Belem"
    var login = document.getElementById("user_login");
    window.localStorage.setItem('usuario', login);
    saveGet();
}

function saveGet(){
    // Depois, em outra página ou aba, recupera esse item
    var usuario = window.localStorage.getItem('usuario');
    document.getElementById('user_login').value = usuario;
}

function delGet(){

    // Remove o item
    window.localStorage.removeItem('usuario');
}
//Rodar no load do DOM
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
   saveGet();
});
</script>
```

Lembre-se que a outra página deve estar no mesmo domínio para que você possa usar o localStorage.

Comment: estarei testando, em si, de primeiro momento parece-me bem correto dessa maneira, mas queria ajuda realmente no getItem('usuario'); ou seja, ficar getItem('swanvol'); pois é no .value = usuario; que está me indicando o nome da conta, gostaria de ajeitar para retirar esse erro: [object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: A resposta abaixo tem sobre o .value que você não pega na hora de pegar o valor do login, então é salvo um objeto html e por isso sua resposta é a de [object HTMLInputElement]. Acredito que era o que faltava.

Answer (score 0):

Você esqueceu de pegar o `value` do campo `user_login`:

```
                                                    ↓
var login = document.getElementById("user_login").value;
```

Da forma que fez, irá retornar apenas o elemento HTML, e não o que foi digitado nele.